# Trying to connect a ceiling fan with a light

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Im trying to connect a ceiling fan with a light. (Used). There are 2 ceiling wires, orange and white. Fan/light has blue, white, black and green. The black and white wires were initially twisted together. When I connected to the orange ceiling wire, light worked, but  not the fan. I twisted the black and blue together and attached to the orange ceiling wire. White one connected to white one, and green connected to copper base plate of lamp for ground. The light turns on when pull the chain. However, when I pull the chain for the fan, it still doesn't turn. I can hear a "humming" like there is power. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Green is ground and should not matter.  Orange is odd but should be the power/hot wire and white should be the neutral.  Blue/black connected to orange should be right, but black and white is odd.  Can you post pictures of the fan(with instructions)?  I have a bad feeling this is Chinese and might not be safe/right.  Are there UL/CSA marks on the instructions/box?

Comment: Orange is strange. What country are you in.

Comment: @Ruskes  In NA any colour except white(with a few exceptions) and green is allowed for hot.  It is not used that much and is odd to us, but probably more common in conduit only places(Chicago, NY).

Comment: Light works, but fan hums and doesn't spin= fan is bad....used makes it more likely its a bad fan motor.   You can verify the direction switch isn't in the middle, but most likely this used fan is done.

Comment: If the fan has a start capacitor then replace it

Comment: @ Ruskes, didn't know a ceiling fan had a start capacitor.  Where is it usually located?